# Realization of prequantized Hilbert schemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Could we define the product of an integral scheme over an algebraic subvariety of positive characteristic if the non-reduced points are not split-solvable over the field? Perhaps a geometric quantization of the generic Hilbert scheme would produce enough invariants to move the spectrum into the nilpotent radical. But I haven't seen any specific method for producing this kind of conformal transformations on associated algebras. Is there a (non-reductive) group which would render such a functor, from a geometric perspective?